# GLSurfaceView and EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm getting this error occasionally in our game:

```
STACK_TRACE := java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1079)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1037)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1342)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Now, I've read about other instances of this problem being caused by not calling onPause and onResume on the GLSurfaceView, but we are.

BUT! The way our game works, there are several activities, most of which are popup windows.  We don't want the renderer to pause in those instances, since we want the drawing to continue behind the menu.

So we call onPause in the enclosing activity's onStop method, and onResume in the activity's onStart/onRestart method.

A [post on Google](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12378) mentions both the onPause/onResume issue as well as "code to prevent GLThread from being executed at ill times".  Is there something else I do need to do?

(I'm not drawing textures that aren't bound, but that aside, this is happening at the start of the frame, isn't it?  It's not drawing, but swapping the buffer to draw what's been buffered and setting up a blank space for the next frame, isn't it?)

I'd greatly appreciate any insight.